# How to save dynamical fields data to database in laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How to save dynamical fields to database the problem is i don't know the names of fields we have module the user will add fields with name dynamically and i will save that fields names in database when the user checks the form for example he added fields in posts form so i want to save that fields data to database.Here's my code

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="firstname"  id="firstname">
<?php foreach($extrafields as $extrafields1 )
{
?>
<input type="<?php    $extrafields1->type; ?>" name="<?php    $extrafields1->name; ?>"  id="<?php    $extrafields1->id; ?>"  <?php    $extrafields1->extraparameters; ?>>

<?php
}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't define the name of the columns in the database, you'll have to save the data as JSON.  So you'd create a column on your model called `extra_parameters` that would be a text column.  When you post the form data, you'd need to update the model something like this:

```
//remove the expected parameters so you only have the extra ones
$extraparams = $request->except(['firstname','...']);

$model->extra_parameters = $extraparams;
```

You should also cast the column to an array in your model.  This allows you to set `$model->extra_parameters` using an array, and it will automatically convert it to JSON when saving to the DB.  It also lets you use `$model->extra_parameters['param_name']` to access the fields.

```
//in your model file
protected $casts = [
    'extra_parameters' => 'array'
];
```

see the array casting section here for more: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting